# Maven Version Range in Build Section

Tags: java, spring, maven, kotlin

I'm working on a Spring app using Kotlin. When applying the `spring` plugin I noticed some odd behavior. When I use a specific version, i.e. `1.3.60`, it works just fine, but when I try to apply a range, i.e. `[1.3.60,1.4.0)`, it says the plugin is applied, but my `@Service` classes are all still marked as `final`. Why is that?

working pom.xml:

```xml
...
<properties>
  <kotlin.version>1.3.60</kotlin.version>
</properties>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.60</version>
    <!-- other plugin setup -->
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Whereas if I change `kotlin.version` to `[1.3.60,1.4.0)` it will not work.

super simple service for illustration:

```
@Service
class TestService
```

After the `spring` plugin has been applied I should be able to open the `.class` file and see this:

```
package com.so.test

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service public open class TestService public constructor() {
}
```

however what I actually see is this:

```
package com.so.test

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service public final class TestService public constructor() {
}
```

Also, if it's any help the output from Maven is:

```
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:1.3.60:compile (compile) @ kotlin-setup-test ---
[WARNING] Source root doesn't exist: [path to unused java src folder]
[INFO] Applied plugin: 'spring'
[INFO] Applied plugin: 'no-arg'
```

Comment: Can you be more accurate what you mean by `it will not work`?

Comment: I meant "when I try to apply a range, i.e. [1.3.60,1.4.0), it says the plugin is applied, but my @Service classes are all still marked as final."

Comment: Please explain more in detail..did you get an error message if so please add the output ...

Comment: No, no error. As stated, from just looking at the output it looks like everything was applied successfully, but when I look at the `.class` file, it still says the file is final. I've updated my answer with what that looks like vs what I expect as well as the console output

Comment: Ah now I got the problem. First Kotlin defines classes by default as final. The other question arises on that is: What do you use version ranges? If you change the version of the maven plugin you should do that on purpose not based on the things that someone decided to deploy a new version and might break your own build...Furthermore the question is why a service should not be final?

Comment: Spring requires that managed beans not be final. That's the purpose of the `spring` plugin. It allows a developer to maintain the strict standards of Kotlin during development but capitalize on Spring's capabilities at runtime. I was hoping to use a patch range as those don't introduce any breaking changes, but still often provide compiler or tooling improvements that I do want to capitalize on without constantly needing to update every single service every time a new one comes out.